# "jumping" to a specific row in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm facing a very annoying issue the whole day without success solving it, i need to jump to a row in a gridview, the number of a row that i want to jump to is taken from query string.

i have searched google,here and other places, none of the answers i tried worked for me.

the gridview columns are template fields.

this is the last thing i tried :

```
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
                                "navigate",
                                "window.onload = function() {window.location.hash='#" + anchorId + "';}",
                                 true);
```

anchorid is placed in a template item inside a Template Field

ty.

Edit: 
here is some of th gridview code, it's too long and it's poiontless to post it all :

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GV_SeatRent" runat="server" DataSourceID="GridDataSource" EnablePersistedSelection="True"
        AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CssClass="DDGridView"
        RowStyle-CssClass="td" HeaderStyle-CssClass="th" CellPadding="6" 
        PageSize="100" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" 
        Width="300px" onprerender="GV_SeatRent_PreRender" 
        onrowupdated="GV_SeatRent_RowUpdated" onrowupdating="GV_SeatRent_RowUpdating">
        <Columns>

           <asp:TemplateField >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a title="asd" name='<%# setAnchor()%>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

             <asp:TemplateField >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# GetCompName()%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# GetTalmidName()%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your `GridView`?

Comment: What happens when you modify your url to go to the hash, does it work? For instance typing in `www.myurl.com/mypage.aspx#myanchor`.

Comment: nope, not working, though, the name is set properly, i have checked it few times (name of the <a name=...>

Comment: dataGridView.SelectedIndex = indexFromQueryYouMentioned;

//select the row
dataGridView1.Rows[indexFromQueryYouMentioned].Selected = true;
//scroll to the selected row
this.dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = indexFrom;

Comment: John, it's asp.net, Gridview is my case , not DataGrid, ty.